# Is there a rpmbuild that works on macosx?

Tags: macos, macports

I am working on a maven build that needs to make an rpm.  Is there a native rpmbuild utility that will run on MacOSX?  So far I have found some old abandoned macports/darwin projects and people recommending running virtual box/parallels in virtual VM mode.  Is there really no native tool for building rpms on Mac?

Comment: Where should the rpms be installed afterwards, on a Linux system?

Comment: We strongly discourage questions that ask a yes/no answer. Consider editing this to describe exactly what practical problem you are facing if you don't actually want answers that state - "No - there is no native package manager rpm that ships with OS X."

Answer (score 2):

Building RPMs or more specifically the binaries/libraries within them on a Mac is not a safe bet because you can run into a number of issues involving architecture mismatches, among other issues like library linking.

In short, if you're building for Linux, you really want to build on Linux. It's possible to cross-compile, but IMHO this is incredibly difficult on OS X.

Comment: What does the rpm contain, if made via maven then likely to be pure java - if so then this answer does not apply

Answer (score 1):

I've tried [homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) to install somewhat recent versions of the tool. The package for rpm installs fine but rpmbuild does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to seperately install rpmbuild. After installation of rpm, the command rpmbuild also works.

Comment: How do you install rpm?